# Repeat PlotStyle for different functions

Tags: plotting, options, style

I am trying to plot a helicoid using [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html).

I would like all the functions that make it up to appear the same.

**I am curious if there is a way I can do that other that by repeating the same [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) 3 times--surely there must be some syntax shortcut?**

But I have not found it?

What I have - notice the redundancy in `{{Opacity[0.5], Pink},{Opacity[0.5], Pink},{Opacity[0.5], Pink}}`. Surely there must be a better way?

```
Plot3D[
 {ArcTan[y/x] - Pi, ArcTan[y/x] , ArcTan[y/x] + Pi} 
, {x, -Pi, Pi}
, {y, -Pi, Pi}
, PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0.5], Pink},{Opacity[0.5], Pink},{Opacity[0.5], Pink}}
]
```

Comment: See [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html), "Details," first bullet point.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Pink]
```

to have all functions in the first argument of `Plot3D` style `Pink` with `Opacity` .5.